# No network access after receiving FCM High priority

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In order to check if a person is still 'online' in some kind of chat app, we use Firebase to send a FCM high priority and the device should answer in the next seconds.

---

**In the documentation, we can read**

> FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing
>   the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run
>   some limited processing (including very limited network access).

- It works between 30 minutes to few hours, but at some point the network is not accessible from the phone and I am receiving a socket timeout. My app is set as 'not optimized' in the battery section.
- I even try to start a WorkManager job with a 'NetworkType.CONNECTED' constraints, but even with that I have a timeout after some time.

Any idea of how to avoid these timeouts ? And what Firebase means by 'very limited network access' ?

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem. My app is also set as **not optimized** in battery optimization section. Then I also set google play services as **not optimized**. And if you are connecting your device with wifi then **set wifi to be enabled even in deep sleep mode**. However, LTE works fine even with device in sleep.